# What is the point of views in pandas if it is undefined whether an indexing operation returns a view or a copy?

Tags: python, pandas, view, slice

I have switched from R to pandas. I routinely get SettingWithCopyWarnings, when I do something like

```py
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4]})    

# Filtering step, which may or may not return a view
df_b = df_a[df_a['col1'] > 1]

# Add a new column to df_b
df_b['new_col'] = 2 * df_b['col1']

# SettingWithCopyWarning!!
```

I think I understand the problem, though I'll gladly learn what I got wrong. In the given example, it is undefined whether `df_b` is a view on `df_a` or not. Thus, the effect of assigning to `df_b` is unclear: does it affect `df_a`? The problem can be solved by explicitly making a copy when filtering:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1,2,3,4]})    

# Filtering step, definitely a copy now
df_b = df_a[df_a['col1'] > 1].copy()

# Add a new column to df_b
df_b['new_col'] = 2 * df_b['col1']

# No Warning now
```

I think there is something that I am missing: if we can never really be sure whether we create a view or not, what are views good for? From the pandas documentation (http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html?highlight=view#indexing-view-versus-copy)

> Outside of simple cases, it’s very hard to predict whether it [**getitem**] will return a view or a copy (it depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no guarantees)

Similar warnings can be found for different indexing methods.

I find it very cumbersome and errorprone to sprinkle .copy() calls throughout my code. Am I using the wrong style for manipulating my DataFrames? Or is the performance gain so high that it justifies the apparent awkwardness?

Comment: You can safely disable this new warning with the following assignment. `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None`

Comment: Hmmm, maybe help reset index `df_b = df_a[df_a['col1'] > 1].reset_index(drop=True)`.

Comment: @GeorgePetrov I would strongly suggest against disabling that! The warning comes up for a good reason -- if anything, I would actually suggest you promote it to an exception instead of a warning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Great question!

The short answer is: this is a flaw in pandas that's being remedied.

You can find a longer discussion of the nature of [the problem here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10954), but the main take-away is that we're now moving to a "copy-on-write" behavior in which any time you slice, you get a new copy, and you never have to think about views. The fix will soon come through this [refactoring project.](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11970) I actually tried to fix it directly ([see here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11500)), but it just wasn't feasible in the current architecture.

In truth, we'll keep views in the background -- they make pandas SUPER memory efficient and fast when they can be provided -- but we'll end up hiding them from users so, from the user perspective, if you slice, index, or cut a DataFrame, what you get back will effectively be a new copy.

(This is accomplished by creating views when the user is only reading data, but whenever an assignment operation is used, the view will be converted to a copy before the assignment takes place.)

Best guess is the fix will be in within a year -- in the mean time, I'm afraid some `.copy()` may be necessary, sorry!

Comment: Update from 2024: [Copy-on-Write](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/copy_on_write.html) mode is available, and will become the default in pandas 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

I agree this is a bit funny. My current practice is to look for a "functional" method for whatever I want to do (in my experience these almost always exist with the exception of renaming columns and series). Sometimes it makes the code more elegant, sometimes it makes it worse (I don't like `assign` with `lambda`), but at least I don't have to worry about mutability.

So for indexing, instead of using the slice notation, you can use `query` which will return a copy by default:

```
In [5]: df_a.query('col1 > 1')
Out[5]:
   col1
1     2
2     3
3     4
```

I expand on it a little in [this blog post.](http://themrmax.github.io/2015/10/12/functional-pipelines-in-pandas.html)

**Edit:** As raised in the comments, it looks like I'm wrong about `query` returning a copy by default, however if you use the `assign` style, then assign will make a copy before returning your result, and you're all good:

```
df_b = (df_a.query('col1 > 1')
            .assign(newcol = 2*df_a['col1']))
```

Comment: Why does the sequence: `df_b = df_a.query('col1 > 1')` followed by `df_b['new_col'] = 2 * df_b['col1']` still give the SettingWithCopyWarning?

Comment: @maxymoo: This answers the second part of my question: a programming style to avoid SettingWithCopy issues. Thanks! I really liked your blog post! Can you answer the question from screenpaver? I think most of the suggestions in your blog post work very well, but .query() does not seem to return a copy in all cases! So I can I do filtering in a method chain?

Comment: Yes, thanks.  Or this will work also (without query): `df_b = df_a[df_a.col1>1].assign(newcol = 2*df_a['col1'])`