# Is Pandas DataFrame df.loc a view or a new DataFrame object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Title says it. In the accepted answer to [StackOverflow 34884536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884536/what-is-the-point-of-views-in-pandas-if-it-is-undefined-whether-an-indexing-oper) it says

> You can find a longer discussion of the nature of the problem here,
>   but the main take-away is that we're now moving to a "copy-on-write"
>   behavior in which any time you slice, you get a new copy, and you
>   never have to think about views.
>
> ...
>
> Best guess is the fix will be in within a year -- in the mean time,
>   I'm afraid some .copy() may be necessary, sorry!
>
> (answered 2016/01/20)

Does df.loc[] return a 'copy' now? Or to be safe do I still have to use .copy()?

Answer (score 1):

It returns a copy. You can test this by making a copy, assigning an index via .loc to another variable, changing the variable, and noticing that the original frame doesn't change.

Slightly related, but further info here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Answer (score 0):

It may return a copy or a view depending on the underlying structure of the dataframe. To be safe you should use .copy()

A good example of the difference in behavior is given there:
[In Pandas, does .iloc method give a copy or view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972633/in-pandas-does-iloc-method-give-a-copy-or-view)